# django reversing admin urls with underscores

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

To reverse a model url for Django Admin, you need to write `admin:appname_modelname_change` . But what if the model name has underscores?

I have a model called `AdNetwork` inside an app called `pubscout`, and I am trying to reverse its url.

`admin:pubscout_adnetwork_change` doesn't work

`admin:pubscout_ad_network_change` doesn't work either

How to fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve your problem, but you shouldn't use underscore in model names. Models are python classes, they should use CapWords convention, like `AdNetwork`. PEP 8 doc: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: yes, my model is `AdNetwork`, without underscores. How should the url for it look like? the above versions don't work. THe underscore version above was just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please can you show us your code.

```
reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (app_label, model_name), args=(object_id,))
```

Something like this should work:

```
reverse('admin:pubscout_adnetwork_change', args=(object_id,))
```

... where `object_id` is an `AdNetwork` pk.

Please make you have registered the `AdNetwork` model and hooked the AdminSite instances into your URLconf.

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls

Comment: Yeah right, I had the arguments wrong. I was doing `reverse_lazy('admin:pubscout_adnetwork_change', kwargs={'pk': obj.ad_network.pk})` . Your way, with `args` instead of `kwargs`, works perfectly. Thanks!